# How do I install upstart on CentOS 5.9?

Tags: centos, upstart

YUM doesn't have upstart.  I installed the package under NPM, but I don't think that's what I want.  I know there's a package for apt-get, but CentOS doesn't have apt-get (at least, not by default).

So...  pretty newbie question, I know, but how do I install under CentOS 5.9?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got software that's in Debian package manager (apt-get) format, and you want to install it on a Linux that uses RPM (yum) format ...

... your best bet is to install something like [RPMForge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge):

- http://everyday-tech.com/apt-get-on-centos/